# What is the difference between the 'Pivot table' and 'Contingency table'?

Tags: contingency-tables, pivot-table

Is there any difference? Or they are basically the same? Just Excel users call it 'pivot table' and statistically-minded people call it 'contingency table'?

Comment: As far as I know, "pivot table" is a software device term and contingency table is a statistical term. Any electronic table where you can mouse-drag data categories from columns to rows, from rows to layers or other way, and do other flexible restructuring - is a pivot table. Contingency table is just a crosstabulation (most often, frequency) where cell entries tell about some sort of "affinity" between rows and columns. It can be on paper, not only electronic.

Comment: For a related question -- about what a pivot table *is* how they can be useful, see [*What are pivot tables, and how can they be helpful in analyzing data?*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374/what-are-pivot-tables-and-how-can-they-be-helpful-in-analyzing-data)

Comment: In principle, a contingency table can have any number of dimensions, one, two, three, and so forth. Clearly even three dimensions can be awkward to handle but that is a practical issue. Often a multidimensional contingency table may just be represented in list form. **A complicated contingency table might never be listed as such, but analysed with some model and studied through model output.** So it's important to realise that a contingency table is not defined by having rows and columns. I can't comment equivalently on pivot tables and how many dimensions they may have.

Answer (score 6):

You may create a **contingency table** using a software tool called **pivot table** :)

A **contingency table** is a crosstable with rows, columns and data related to each of the row/column combination. You may draw such a table on a piece of paper, you may use an [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube) as the source of data etc. As [this site](http://www.eumetrain.org/data/4/451/english/msg/ver_categ_forec/uos1/uos1_ko1.htm) says, a contingency table is essentially a display format used to analyse and record the relationship between two or more categorical variables.

A **pivot table** is one of the possible ways of creating a contingency table. A typical pivot table has the visual form of the contingency table, although a pivot table might have only one column or even zero etc. The pivot operation in spreadsheet software can be used to generate a contingency table from sampling data. However you may use the pivot table as a tool to play with the data in other ways, too.

Comment: Thank you--I had noticed that when you made the change over a year ago (and upvoted your answer then).